# An archive page without post format (just standard post)

Tags: wp-query, loop, post-formats

I'm trying to get posts with not marked with any type of post types (aside, audio etc). But I didn't find any solution to do this. I thought doing this with custom fields but site has a lot of posts...

Comment: If indeed you're asking about post *format*, please update your post title and question so it's clear for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're asking about post **format** and not post **type**. Assuming that's correct, you'll probably be using `WP_Query` to query all posts of the post format "Standard." However, as noted in this trac ticket, there's strangely [no way to query for the standard post format](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16149). Instead you need to query for all posts `NOT IN` any other format.

[Alex King put together a fairly involved snippet that does this.](http://alexking.org/blog/2012/01/05/wp_query-by-standard-post-format)

A simpler snippet is found in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735286/597678) to a similar question:

```
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('post-format-quote','post-format-audio','post-format-gallery','post-format-image','post-format-link','post-format-video', 'post-format-aside'),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)
```

The above would be the value of the `tax_query` argument in an instance of `WP_Query`.

Comment: I added 'post-format-aside' to in my code and it solved my problem thank you @mrwweb. updated title ^^.

Comment: Good catch. Code updated.